# How do I get the ship to city from a shipment?

Tags: module, shipping, shipment

I have been browsing http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Customer/Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract.html for a while now, and I am not seeing anything about retrieving the city from the Address...

How do I retrieve the ship to city from the shipment class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract` is an abstract class and you cannot get address values from this class. Following address classes extends from `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract` class:

```
1. Mage_Customer_Model_Address
2. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
3. Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address
```

And you can retrieve shipping address from shipment via this way:

```
/**
 * @var $shipment Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment
 * @var $order    Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
$shipmentId  = 1;
$incrementId = 100000001;
$shipment    = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);
$city        = $shipment->getShippingAddress()->getCity();

//or you can load shipment address via order
$order       = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$shipment    = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
$anotherCity = $shipment->getShippingAddress()->getCity();
print_r($anotherCity->getData());
```

By the way `$shipment->getShippingAddress()` method returns us order shipping address, see `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve shipping address
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address
 */
public function getShippingAddress()
{
    return $this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
}
```

If you understand examples given above, order and shipment address is same object. This class is `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address` and you can retrieve it's values (street, city, region, country, postcode, ...) via Magento's magic **getSomeValue** methods.